# Is it possible to not use all your votes in the election phase?

Tags: support, election

If you were to, for example, omit your third choice vote in the election phase, would your first and second choice vote still count?

Comment: Interestingly, there are a lot of people who only end up using their second or third place votes, and none of the others. I would really like to ask them why.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't be using my first and second choice.  I would only use my first to vote for myself.